# ng-click em button dentro de um label

Tags: angularjs, ionic, angularjs-scope

Minha intenção é que apareça um botão de close dentro do `input` para que, ao clicar nele, a query de busca seja remontada e retorne todos os itens novamente e não mais apenas os da busca em questão. Esse botão deverá sumir enquanto o usuário não digitar novamente no campo de busca. Parece que fiz tudo certo, mas o `ng-click` não está funcionando no `button` dentro do elemento `label`. Vejam o código:

```
<label class="item-input-wrapper">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar por Evento" ng-model="busca.evento">
    <button class="button" ng-hide="btnZerar" ng-click="zerar()">
        <i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i>
    </button>
</label>
```

E no controller:

```
$scope.zerar = function() {
   $scope.btnZerar = true;
   carregaEventosInicio();
};
```

Observação: Estou usando o Ionic Framework.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por quê não usa uma `div` ao invés de `label`?

Comment: Você salvou meu trabalho.Obrigado Techies.

Comment: Por nada @David :p

Comment: Coloque a solução do problema como resposta caso tenha resolvido.

Comment: Não sei como se faz isso.

Comment: aperta no ícone de "Check" em baixo da seta de votação da resposta dele ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa `Label` ela substitui o click do botão, por isso seu botão não funciona. Troque essa `label` por uma `div` que irá funcionar.